# What is the largest class of functions $f$ such that the map $\pi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f \ d\pi$ is continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

What is the largest class of functions $f$ such that the map $\pi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f \ d\pi$ is continuous, where $\pi$ is a probability measure? Further, what if $\pi$ is a probability measure with finite first moments in each marginal? That is, $\pi$ has marginals $\mu_i$ with finite first moments on each $\mathbb{R}_i$, $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}_1 \times ... \times \mathbb{R}_n$. I am taking the weak topology.

I know that the first class contains continuous bounded functions, and the second contains functions $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$ bounded by $K(1 + \lvert x_1 \rvert + ... + \lvert x_n \rvert$), but I want to know if I can expand these.

Thanks!

Comment: For $\pi \mapsto \int f d\pi$ a linear functional on the space of finite measures such that if $\forall g \in C^0 \cap L^\infty, \int g d\pi_n\to \int g d\pi$ then $\int f d\pi_n \to \int f d\pi$, you can look at $f_k(x) = \int_{-1/k}^{1/k} f(x) k (1-|kx|) dx$, then $f_k \in C^0$, if $f_k \not \in L^\infty$ let $|f_k(x_m)|\to \infty$, for some choice of $(b_m) \in \ell_1$ you'll have $\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m f_k(x_m)= \infty$ so $f_k$ and $f$ weren't continuous on finite measures.